# Fabric Js i-text chopped/cuts last words of text when using custom font

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I am using Fabric Js 2.7.0 version and I am making a text editor where user can add/update new texts and choose custom fonts for that text.

When user saves his changes I am generating json from canavs and store that in DB But issue is when we load same json in the canvas editor last few word of text cut/ chopped.

`var Addtext = function() { 
canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Click to edit text', { 
      left: canvasWidthCenter,
      top:  canvasHeightCenter,
      fontFamily: "myriad pro",
      fill: "#fff",
      fontSize: "50",
      originX: "center",
      originY: "center",`

}));

};

Comment: Are you using `toJSON()` and `loadFromJSON()`? Can you provide more code that shows what doesn't work?

Comment: @shkaper I am using  <code>toJSON()</code> get json of canvas to save and <code> loadFromJSON() </code> to reload in canvas

Sample code:

Load json in canvas
 <code>
 canvas.loadFromJSON(value, function(obj) {
         canvas.renderAll();
    
     }); </code>

Get Json from Canvas
<code>
 JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON([]));
</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented patch mentioned on https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/2612 and it fixed my issue.